# change the signature in PSPDF dynamiclly

Tags: ios, pspdfkit

I am new to `PSPDF`, I want to make the signature functionality user base.

Lets say my userID is 22 and I have signed a PDF from `PSPDF`. Now when I login with other user(userID 23) at that 
I open the signature view from `PSPDF` at that time I want that the signature which I have done from userID 22 will not display. what ever signature I have done from userID 23 will show.

It is possible, if yes then how can I manage this.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance